# Camel Spring JavaConfig Maven-Camel-Plugin without any xml

Tags: java, spring, maven, apache-camel, jbossfuse

How can I setup my camel projects to completely rely on the Spring Dependency injection system while being xml free using the maven camel run plugin.  I have tried a ton of configurations, but I still seem to be stuck with a "shell context" file that just imports my java configuration file.  Is there anyway to get rid of this? Note: also on latest camel version of 2.17.1

Camel Route

```
@Component
public class TestRoute extends SpringRouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("timer://foo?repeatCount=1")
            .log("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Java Config

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.mcf.xml.free.route")
public class RouteJavaConfig extends CamelConfiguration {

}
```

Maven Camel Plugin

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${camel.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configClasses>com.mcf.xml.free.config.RouteJavaConfig</configClasses>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Plugin Context that lets it all work that I want to get rid of.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

  <context:annotation-config/>
  <bean class="com.mcf.xml.free.config.RouteJavaConfig"/>
</beans>
```

Is there some way to have the maven camel run plugin accept the Java Config instead of a Spring Context file?  Also I haven't tested this yet, but If removing this file is going to cause an issue deploying to Apache Karaf is there a way to have it configured to use my Java Config as well?

Comment: I am asking this out of curiosity. Why would you want to get rid of this one tiny file?

Comment: Simply for maintenance and refactoring purposes.  Xml based configuration is very difficult to safely refactor with IDE tools.  Ideally my base project should have no xml unless it would be for some sort of legacy dependency support.  I tend to create a lot of applications that are subject to major amounts of refactoring so cleaning up anything that slows that down is really ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start your Spring Java Config application using a main class you create yourself, and then use the java-maven-exec plugin to run it. This example has no XML file at all.

There is an example as part of Apache Camel at: https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples/camel-example-spring-javaconfig

Comment: Is the camel maven plugin incompatible with Java configuration?

Comment: Yes then you need to either configure the plugin mainClass option and point to a main like used in that example in the link provided, or to configure configClasses or basedPackages option on the plugin. The latter two are for spring java main.

Comment: @ClausIbsen And could can run this example in Fuse with no issues?

Answer (score 0):

I think your scenario is a great fit for using spring boot with camel. Spring quotes:

> Absolutely **no code generation** and **no requirement for XML** configuration

on their page. [Spring-Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/)

Here is one Spring boot-camel example you can have a look at to check: [Camel-Spring Boot example](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/examples/camel-example-spring-boot)

Comment: I am definitely in agreement that Spring Boot is awesome, however,  I would like to workout what my options are if I specifically stay on the FUSE  platform (Camel, Spring, OSGI, CXF, Karaf)